# How to impl go wasm promise await

Tags: go, webassembly

here is my code

```
func Await(p js.Value) js.Value {
    var r js.Value
    var e string
    done := make(chan struct{})

    p.Call("then", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        r = args[0]
        done <- struct{}{}
        return nil
    })).Call("catch", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) any {
        var err = args[0]
        e = fmt.Sprintf("%v\n%v", err, err.Get("stack").String())
        done <- struct{}{}
        return nil
    }))

    // Wait for the Promise to resolve here instead of after the p.Call
    <-done
    if e != "" {
        panic(JsErr{Msg: e})
    }

    return r
}
```

it often raise err in `<-done` and hard to debug err, is there good way to fix this err

fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

```
goroutine 1 [select (no cases)]:
main.main()
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/test/wasm/testwasm/main.go:18 +0x5

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
gowasmlib/pkg/wasm.Await({{}, 0x7ff8000100000019, 0x4100f0})
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/pkg/wasm/wasm.go:95 +0x15
gowasmlib/pkg/wasm.StorageSet({0x1e92d, 0x1}, {0xd080, 0x39ee0})
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/pkg/wasm/wasm.go:109 +0x7
main.main.func1({{}, 0x7ff8000100000005, 0x4100b0}, {0x129128, 0x0, 0x0})
    /home/roroco/Dropbox/mix/go_wasm/test/wasm/testwasm/main.go:13 +0x2
syscall/js.handleEvent()
    /home/roroco/.goenv/versions/1.20.4/src/syscall/js/func.go:94 +0x26
exit code:
2
```